# Make hidden input field visible HTML Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

**Html input field is inside anchor tag like so ..**

```
<a id="brand" onclick="myFunction()" class="brand" ><input id="mytext" onclick="myFunction()" type="hidden" value="Anchor Title">Anchor Title</a>
```

**Javascript uses set attribute**

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("brand").innerHTML = "";

    document.getElementById("mytext").setAttribute("type", "text");

    var elem = document.getElementById("mytext");

    elem.value = "Edit Title";

    document.getElementById("brand").innerHTML = elem.value;
    }
</script>
```

**ACTUAL RESULTS**

- Anchor title is cleared on click
- But, the input field is still hidden

**Wanting To Achieve**

- Anchor title cleared on click
- Input text field appears
- User inputs text
- Text from input becomes anchor title
- Input field becomes hidden again

Comment: Try `text`, instead of `value`: `document.getElementById("mytext").setAttribute("type", "text");`.

Comment: @vee This creates the same result, but thank you for the response.

Comment: It looks like your last line is replacing the content of `brand` anchor tag with just the text.  It's not that the input field is hidden, it's removed.

Comment: @vee So, the .innerHTML method is recreating my `brand` anchor tag to be: `<a id="brand" onclick="myFunction()" class="brand" >Anchor Title</a> without the input tag?

Comment: Yes, the `.innerHTML` is replacing the content of `brand`.  Is there a reason why you're not using `jQuery` with `Rails`?

Comment: @vee I was unaware of jQuery. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OlzNEYh5q5IoCC5hjAny?p=preview) using DOM.  I would strongly recommend jQuery for the simplicity it provides.  Take a look into [toogle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) for this specific issue.

Comment: @vee Thanks. The plunker shows exactly what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove the line:

```
document.getElementById("brand").innerHTML = "";
```

(I don't know but maybe you delete the input element by that.)

Answer (score 0):

Notice that when you do *document.getElementById("brand").innerHTML = "";* you are deleting all things there are between `<a id="brand">` and `</a>`, in this case the `<input>` line.

My solution:

```
<html>

    <script>
    function myFunction1() {
        var elem1 = document.getElementById("mytext1")
        elem1.setAttribute("type", "text");
        elem1.value="Edit Title";
        document.getElementById("mytext2").innerHTML = "";
    }

    function myFunction2() {
        var elem1 = document.getElementById("mytext1")
        elem1.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        document.getElementById("mytext2").innerHTML = elem1.value;
    }
    </script>


    <a id="brand" onclick="myFunction1()" class="brand" >
        <input id="mytext1" onchange="myFunction2()" type="hidden" value="Anchor Title">
        <span id="mytext2">Anchor Title</span>
    </a>

</html>
```